# How to save remote workspace locally on VS Code

Tags: macos, visual-studio-code

I have set up a remote workspace via SSH. I want to save the workspace locally, so I can double click to launch with everything in place. However, when I choose "Save Workspace As" there is no option for "Show Local".

This is something I've done before hundreds of times, not sure if the last update has broken this (1.51.0), or if I have misremembered how I achieved it.

Answer (score 0):

It seems this was an intentional change that has been reverted. I'm guessing will be available in the next release. In the meantime, I have been creating manual workspace files based on the format used by previous successful saves. https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/109713

Answer (score -1):

F1 > Log Level > Trace

```
[2021-04-16 22:30:50.783] [renderer4] [trace] load() - enter {"$mid":1,"fsPath":"c:\\QGB\\babun\\cygwin\\bin\\qgb\\__main__.py","_sep":1,"external":"file:///c%3A/QGB/babun/cygwin/bin/qgb/__main__.py","path":"/C:/QGB/babun/cygwin/bin/qgb/__main__.py","scheme":"file"}
[2021-04-16 22:30:53.559] [renderer4] [trace] CommandService#executeCommand workbench.action.files.openFile
[2021-04-16 22:30:53.569] [renderer4] [trace] telemetry/workbenchActionExecuted {"id":"workbench.action.files.openFile","from":"keybinding"}


[2021-04-16 22:48:08.989] [renderer4] [trace] load() - enter {"$mid":1,"fsPath":"c:\\QGB\\babun\\cygwin\\bin\\qgb\\__main__.py","_sep":1,"external":"file:///c%3A/QGB/babun/cygwin/bin/qgb/__main__.py","path":"/C:/QGB/babun/cygwin/bin/qgb/__main__.py","scheme":"file"}
[2021-04-16 22:48:09.551] [renderer4] [trace] telemetry/editorOpened {"typeId":"workbench.editors.files.fileEditorInput","resource":{"mimeType":"text/x-bat, text/plain","scheme":"file","ext":".cmd","path":-1715722077}}
[2021-04-16 22:48:09.646] [renderer4] [trace] load() - enter {"$mid":1,"fsPath":"c:\\QGB\\babun\\cygwin\\bin\\qgb\\!.cmd","_sep":1,"external":"file:///c%3A/QGB/babun/cygwin/bin/qgb/%21.cmd","path":"/C:/QGB/babun/cygwin/bin/qgb/!.cmd","scheme":"file"}
[2021-04-16 22:48:09.773] [renderer4] [trace] load() - resolved content {"$mid":1,"fsPath":"c:\\QGB\\babun\\cygwin\\bin\\qgb\\!.cmd","_sep":1,"external":"file:///c%3A/QGB/babun/cygwin/bin/qgb/%21.cmd","path":"/C:/QGB/babun/cygwin/bin/qgb/!.cmd","scheme":"file"}
[2021-04-16 22:48:09.785] [renderer4] [trace] load() - created text editor model {"$mid":1,"fsPath":"c:\\QGB\\babun\\cygwin\\bin\\qgb\\!.cmd","_sep":1,"external":"file:///c%3A/QGB/babun/cygwin/bin/qgb/%21.cmd","path":"/C:/QGB/babun/cygwin/bin/qgb/!.cmd","scheme":"file"}
[2021-04-16 22:48:09.800] [renderer4] [trace] telemetry/fileGet {"mimeType":"text/x-bat, text/plain","ext":".cmd","path":-1715722077,"reason":1}
```